# Using event function in matlab ode45 for multi-dimensional state vector

Tags: matlab, events, ode

I have a set of odes written in matrix form as $X' = AX$; I also have a desired value of the states $X_des$. $X$ is a five dimensional vector. I want to stop the integration after all the states reach their desired values (or atleast close to them by $1e{-3}$). How do I use event function  in matlab to do this? (All the help I have seen are about 1 dimensional states)

PS: I know for sure that all the states approach their desired values after long time. I just want to stop the integration once they are $1e{-3}$ within the desired values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I presume that you're aware that you can use the [matrix exponential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential) ([`expm`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/expm.html) in Matlab) to solve your system of linear differential equations directly.

There are many ways to accomplish what you're trying to do. They all depend a bit on your system, how it behaves, and the particular event you want to capture. Here's a small example for a 2-by-2 system of linear differential equations:

```
function multipleeventsdemo
A = [-1 1;1 -2]; % Example A matrix
tspan = [0 50];  % Initial and final time
x0 = [1;1];      % Initial conditions
f = @(t,y)A*y;   % ODE function
thresh = 0;      % Threshold value
tol = 1e-3;      % Tolerance on threshold

opts = odeset('Events',@(t,y)events(t,y,thresh,tol)); % Create events function
[t,y] = ode45(f,tspan,x0,opts);                       % Integrate with options
figure;
plot(t,y);

function [value,isterminal,direction] = events(t,y,thresh,tol)
value = y-thresh-tol;
isterminal = all(y-thresh-tol<=0)+zeros(size(y)); % Change termination condition
direction = -1;
```

Integration is stopped when both states are within `tol` of `thresh`. This is accomplished by adjusting the `isterminal` output of the events function. Note that separate tolerance and threshold variables isn't really necessary – you simply need to define the crossing value.

If your system oscillates as it approaches it's steady state (if `A` has complex eigenvalues), then you'll need to do more work. But you questions doesn't indicate this. And again, numerical integration may not be the easiest/best way to solve your problem which such a system. Here is how you could use `expm` in conjunction with a bit of symbolic math:

```
A = [-1 1;1 -2];
x0 = [1;1];
tol = 1e-3;
syms t_sym
y = simplify(expm(A*t_sym)*x0)           % Y as a function of t
t0 = NaN(1,length(x0));
for i = 1:length(x0)
    sol = double(solve(y(i)==tol,t_sym)) % Solve for t when y(i) equal to tol
    if ~isempty(sol)                     % Could be no solution, then NaN
        t0(i) = max(sol);                % Or more than one solution, take largest
    end
end
f = matlabFunction(y);                   % Create vectorized function of t
t_vec = linspace(0,max(t0),1e2);         % Time vector
figure;
plot(t_vec,f(t_vec));
```

This will only work for fairly small `A`, however, because of the symbolic math. Numerical approaches using `expm` are also possible and likely more scalable.

Comment: Thanks for the help @horchler. Thanks for information about expm.